# Nodes vertical distance in a legend of a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I have a figure drawn using `tikz`. I am trying to add a legend, which consists in two types of arrows with different meanings. My problem is how to add the correct vertical space between the nodes with arrows.

In the MWE, I have the a reference node and the text within it is separated by `\\`. How can I align the nodes with arrows with latter keeping the same vertical space between the text of nodes `(n2)` and `(n3)` as within `(n1)`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=right,inner ysep=0pt] (n1) {BLA\\ BLB};
    \draw[->,red,align=center] ($(n1.north east)+(1cm,0cm)$) -- ++(0:8pt) node[at end,anchor=west] (n2) {BLA BLA};
    \draw[<-,red] ($(n1.north east)+(1cm,-\baselineskip)$) -- ++(0:8pt) node[at end,anchor=west] (n3) {BLA BLB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Basic solution

This solution provides two keys:

- `line` and
- `line default font`.

The `line` key accepts its argument either with `:` or without `:`. If the colon is given, the value is simply forwarded to the internal `@line` key which uses the part before the colon as a font argument (which hopefully set `\baselineskip` correctly. The part after the `:` is the line number, `1` being the bottom line.

Isn’t the colon present the value of `line default font` will be forwarded to `@line` and will be used as the font-argument.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  line default font/.initial=\normalsize,
  line/.code=\pgfutil@in@{:}{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \pgfkeysalso{@line={#1}}\else
      \pgfkeysalso{@line={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/line default font}:#1}}%
    \fi,
  @line/.code args={#1:#2}{% internal
    \begingroup
      #1%
      \pgfutil@tempcnta#2\relax
      \advance\pgfutil@tempcnta-1\relax
      \pgf@xa\pgfutil@tempcnta\baselineskip\relax
      \pgfmath@returnone\pgf@xa
    \endgroup
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfmathresult pt}}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=right, font=\small, draw=lightgray] (n1) {BL\\ BLB};
    \draw[->] ([line=\small:2,xshift=1cm] n1.base east) -- ++(0:8pt)
                                        node[at end,anchor=base west] (n2) {Line 2};
    \draw[<-] ([line=1,       xshift=1cm] n1.base east) -- ++(0:8pt)
                                            node[at end,anchor=base west] (n3) {Line 1};
    \tikzset{line default font=\small, radius=.6pt}
    \fill ([line=1] n1.base west) circle[]
          ([line=2] n1.base west) circle[] [red];
    \fill ([line=1] n1.base)      circle[]
          ([line=2] n1.base)      circle[];
    \fill ([line=1] n1.text)      circle[]
          ([line=2] n1.text)      circle[] [blue];
    \fill ([line=1] n1.base east) circle[]
          ([line=2] n1.base east) circle[] [green];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Sophisticated solution

This solution includes:

- the `save baseline` key that saves the `\baselineskip` length at the end of the node in a macro (it might be helpful to include this style in the `every node` style);
- an addition to the explicit node coordinate system in the form of the `line` key (it checks whether `save baseline` has been used on the node); and
- an addition to the implicit node coordinate. The line is separated from the anchor by the character `'` (it is not possible to use `:` or `,`, it could be possible to use `.` again).

It is not possible to use the `line` key without an anchor (implicitly or explicitly). This could be fixed. I advise against using `'` in a node name (especially if it should be possible to use the line `'` without an anchor).

#### Shortcomings

*Don’t transform!*

Seriously, if either the node is rotated or the path which uses the line-anchor is rotated or one of the `scale`ings is active I can guarantee nothing.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  save baseline/.style={
    execute at end node=\expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@sh@bls@\tikz@fig@name\endcsname{\the\baselineskip}
  }
}
\pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs}{%
  line/.store in=\tikz@cs@line,% addition
  anchor/.store in=\tikz@cs@angle% small fix to reduce the code of the 'node' cs
}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{node}{%
  \tikzset{cs/.cd,name=,anchor=none,line=none,#1}%
  \ifx\tikz@cs@angle\tikz@nonetext%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@cs@node\endcsname\tikz@coordinate@text%
    \else
      \aftergroup\tikz@shapebordertrue%
      \edef\tikz@shapeborder@name{\tikz@cs@node}%
    \fi%
    \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@cs@node}{center}%
  \else%
    \ifx\tikz@cs@line\tikz@nonetext
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@cs@node}{\tikz@cs@angle}%
    \else
      \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@bls@\tikz@cs@node\endcsname\relax
        \PackageError{TikZ}{The \tikz@cs@node\space has no saved baseline, use the 'save baseline' option}{}
        \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@cs@node}{\tikz@cs@angle}
      \else
        \pgfutil@tempcnta=\tikz@cs@line\relax
        \advance\pgfutil@tempcnta-1\relax
        \pgfutil@tempdima=\csname pgf@sh@bls@\tikz@cs@node\endcsname
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@cs@node}{\tikz@cs@angle}}
                    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempcnta\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi%
}
\def\tikz@calc@anchor#1.#2\tikz@stop{%
  \pgfutil@in@{'}{#2}
  \ifpgfutil@in@
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@bls@#1\endcsname\relax
      \PackageError{TikZ}{The #1 has no saved baseline, use the 'save baseline' option}{}
      \pgfpointanchor{#1}{#2}
    \else
      \tikz@calc@anchor@line#1.#2\tikz@stop
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\def\tikz@calc@anchor@line#1.#2'#3\tikz@stop{%
  \pgfutil@tempcnta=#3\relax
  \advance\pgfutil@tempcnta-1\relax
  \pgfutil@tempdima=\csname pgf@sh@bls@#1\endcsname
  \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{#2}}
              {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempcnta\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=right, font=\small, draw=lightgray, save baseline] (n1) {BL\\ BLB};
    \draw[->] (node cs: name=n1, anchor=base east, line=2) -- ++(0:8pt)
                                        node[at end,anchor=base west] (n2) {Line 2};
    \draw[<-] (node cs: name=n1, anchor=base east) -- ++(0:8pt)
                                            node[at end,anchor=base west] (n3) {Line 1};
    \tikzset{radius=.6pt}
    \fill (n1.base west'1) circle[]
          (n1.base west'2) circle[] [red];
    \fill (n1.base'1)      circle[]
          (n1.base'2)      circle[];
    \fill (n1.text'1)      circle[]
          (n1.text'2)      circle[] [blue];
    \fill (n1.base east'1) circle[]
          (n1.base east'2) circle[] [green];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It gives `l.6 ...[->,red] ([line=2,xshift=1cm] n1.base east) -- ++(0:8pt) ?`

Comment: The code works now. But the vertical space is correct only if `font=\normalsize`. Since I am using `font=\small` for all the nodes, I had to do `\tikzset{line/.style={shift={(+0pt,{(#1-1)*\baselineskip*0.91})}}}`. This `0.91` is achieved by trial-error tentatives. How can we introduce a factor if font size chances to `\small`, `\footnotesize`, etc.?

Comment: @cacamailg Yes, that is annoying (and is one of the things I meant with “[i]f `\baselineskip` is not specifically changed inside the node”). I am afraid there is no easy solution. If you typeset all nodes in `\small` you could issue `\small` after `\begin{tikzpicture}[…]` (which changes also all `em` and `ex` dimensions of course). Or you can use `([/utils/exec=\small,line=2,xshift=1cm] n1.base east)` (best hidden in another style). If you want to go very sophisticated, you let `\baselineskip` be stored away and reference it later (could be a special `cs`). Would this be needed?

Comment: Well, all nodes are typeset in `\small` because of space constraints. That special style that you mention, probably is the best solution, because I don't know if I need to typeset some nodes in `\footnotesize`. Or change the style that you have defined to include a second parameter.

Comment: @cacamailg Please see my update. The “Sophisticated solution” is what I was talking about in my previous comment. But don’t use any transformations (besides shifting I think). This could go horrible wrong (but that's true even for the other solutions). I will take a look into the transformations nonetheless.

Comment: I didn't think this could go that further. Very good!